# How to determine if a map is an Open map?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ function (differentiable class $C^1$) with the differentiation matrix invertible for every point in domain. Then $f$ is an open map.

What if that differentiation matrix is not invertible? It doesn't means that the map is not open. Then how we will find if a map is open or not in case of non-invertible differentiation matrix?

Comment: The question is way to general to be answered in this generality (IMHO). Just one possible answer: by **invariance of domain**, it suffices if $f$ is continuous and (locally) injective, but I don't think that this is a necessary condition. So you could ask again "if $f$ is not locally injective, how will we find if $f$ is open or not".